# React Change inner function of parent component using functional component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I have two components: one parent and one in child component as shown below:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useDocumentTitle = (title) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title])
}

function App(){
  const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
  const incrementCount = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrementCount = () => setCount(count - 1);
  const newDivElem = () => { return ( <>Hello World </>)}
  useDocumentTitle(`You clicked ${count} times`);

  return (
    <>
     Count of this value {count}
      <br />
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>&nbsp;
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
      {newDivElem()}
    </>
  );
}

export default App; 

function InternalApp(){
     return(
        <App />
    );
}
export default InternalApp;
```

How can I overwrite the App component inner function `newDivElem()` inside the InternalApp component?

Please suggest some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the function to a prop, and set the original function as the default value:

```
const newDivElem = () => { return ( <>Hello World </>)}

function App({ newDivElem = newDivElem }){
  const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
  const incrementCount = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrementCount = () => setCount(count - 1);
  useDocumentTitle(`You clicked ${count} times`);

  return (
    <>
     Count of this value {count}
      <br />
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>&nbsp;
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
      {newDivElem()}
    </>
  );
}
```

If you want to override it, pass another function as the prop:

```
function InternalApp(){
   return(
      <App newDivElem={() => <div>Something Else</div>} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. I am using atomic design top of react.  Is there any possibility to change without passing prop.

Comment: You can use children (same as props but passed slightly differently) or context. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually i have popup component which is already build and used by other developer. In my functional component i need to change the particular function of that popup component both in design and logic.

Comment: I think that a `prop` shouldn't be a problem, since you've got a default `App({ newDivElem = newDivElem })` which is identical to the original functionality. This means that other users won't be effected, but from now on you can replace the function as well.